# Verificando coluna vazia com CASE em MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estou com uma dificuldade para realizar uma consulta numa tabela de clientes. Preciso buscar duas colunas (`nomeCli` e `nomeFantasiaCli`) e transformá-los em um só: `Nome`.

Resumindo, quando o nome do cliente não estiver preenchido na tabela cliente, vou utilizar o nome fantasia da empresa do cliente.

Estou usando a seguinte consulta:

```sql
SELECT (CASE nomeCli
          WHEN NULL THEN nomeFantasiaCli
          ELSE nomeCli
        END ) AS Nome
  FROM cliente
 ORDER BY Nome ASC
```

A consulta funciona. O problema é que ela só preenche a nova coluna `Nome` apenas com o `nomeCli`. Se esse `nomeCli` estiver vazio, deveria preencher com `nomeFantasiaCli`, mas isso não ocorre. Já tentei até trocar o `WHEN NULL` por `WHEN ''`. Mas de nada adiantou.

Como resolver o problema?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar a função COALESCE para isso.

```
  SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(nomeCli,''), nomeFantasiaCli)
  FROM cliente
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiz alguns testes, mas uso SQL SERVER... tenta fazer assim:

```
SELECT (CASE 
      WHEN nomeCli IS NULL THEN nomeFantasiaCli
      ELSE nomeCli
    END ) AS Nome
FROM cliente
ORDER BY Nome ASC
```